# Connection timeout when connecting to server socket in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, sockets, ubuntu

I have a simple java socket client - server program which conducts some simple tasks.
The server code is like:

```
...
ServerSocket srvSocket = new ServerSocket(9977);
.....
```

And the client code is like:

```
Socket mngSocket = new Socket("35.240.238.43", 9977); 

if (mngSocket != null) {
// do somthing
}
```

The above code worked fine if I ran the client and server in different windows machines (Client running in Win 10, Server running in Win Server 2012).

Now, for some reason, I have to run the server on Ubuntu (Client still running in Win 10). In Ubuntu, I already allowed the port 9977 and tcp protocol.

[image]

But the client could not connect to the server. I got exception: "Connection timeout"

What possible causes of the problem?

Comment: try telnet to that port from client and see if it is able to connect to that port

Comment: I got error 'Connection Timeout' when telnet to that IP as well

Comment: see if this command returns the port on Ubuntu : sudo ufw status verbose

Comment: I just update the question with the capture of port allow in Ubuntu.

Comment: check client computer's firewall settings